# cumulative plot in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot a cumulative binomial distribution function using `tikz`. I have created a plot of a binomial distribution function, as shown in the code and figure below, but I need the `y` value to increase by the previous `y` value at each `\j` iteration.

There is a commented line in the code below; I thought this would do what I want, but it doesn't work.

I know I could use a list of coordinates to do what I want, but I want code that can be easily adjusted because ultimately I want several different values of the parameter `\n` (up to `\n=100`).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={binom(\j,\n,\p)=\n!/(\j!*(\n-\j)!)*\p^\j*(1-\p)^(\n-\j);} ] 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{10};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\p}{0.5};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yup}{0};
\begin{axis}[  xlabel=state $j$, ylabel=cumul. dist. $F_{B(10,1/2)}$
  ,axis x line=middle
  ,axis y line=left
  ,xlabel near ticks
  ,domain=0:\n
  ];       
\foreach \j in {0,...,\n} {
\addplot [color=red,domain=(\j-0.5):(\j+0.6)] {\yup+binom(floor(x+0.5),\n,\p)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yup}{0};
%\pgfmathsetmacro{\yup}{binom(\j,\n,\p)};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice minimal example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the assignment to `\yup` global rather than local.  `\pgfmathsetmarco` does not do that.  You have to use `\pgfmathparse` and the `\xdef\yup{\pgfmathresult}` to achieve that.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={binom(\j,\n,\p)=\n!/(\j!*(\n-\j)!)*\p^\j*(1-\p)^(\n-\j);} ] 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{3};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\p}{0.5};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yup}{0};
\begin{axis}[  xlabel=state $j$, ylabel=cumul. dist. $F_{B(10,1/2)}$
  ,axis x line=middle
  ,axis y line=left
  ,xlabel near ticks
  ,domain=0:\n
  ];       
\foreach \j in {0,...,\n} {
\addplot [color=red,domain=(\j-0.5):(\j+0.5)] {\yup+binom(floor(x+0.5),\n,\p)};
\pgfmathparse{\yup+binom(\j,\n,\p)}
\xdef\yup{\pgfmathresult}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, you will find increasing `\n` quickly leads to overflow.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly does what I want, however I have arithmetic overflow when \n is 8 or larger. Is there any way to get around this?    Ahhh...just seen your edit...

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/202554, but I don't immediately see how to implement this in a `declare function`.

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting. I think I might just avoid the overflow issue and read in data from a file. I was hoping to avoid this, since I didn't want the clutter of extra files, but I guess I'll live with it.